# How is the processing for FPS games with massive worlds (like Planetside 2) distributed between servers?

Tags: architecture, networking, client-server, mmo

For such massively sized maps with an insane amount of players *when it came out* (or maybe it still has thousands of players in one general area at once still?), I'm almost certain the entire world is broken into chunks and each chunk is processed on one computer, because simulating the entire thing in tens of milliseconds is almost certainly impossible with today's technology on a single CPU.

The idea straightforward, but that means that they had to solve the "what happens when someone is in block A and shoots to block A + 1, which server decides it? How is it handled? Do both have a vote on what happened?

I'm curious how people engineered their way around this problem, what they found to work and *did not* work.

How can I solve something like this in my own game?